# Javascript - Change Alert Icon

Tags: javascript

Is it possible change javascript alert icons? By default it is showing the warning icon.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No.

Instead, you can create a fake dialog in your page, like [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).