# How to change the style of alert box?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to change the style of the "OK" Button in an *alert* box.

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show_alert() {
            alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Show alert box" />
</body>
```

Comment: Please do not use alert boxes. There are better options. Just use them for debugging.

Comment: lmao @EdHeal, please dont use those for debugging! xD There are better optoins xD

Comment: I started off boring with a boring thing xD http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tFhKu

Comment: Down-voted for accepting jQuery as an "answer". The correct answer is to advocate for an attempt to standardize something in a CSS spec.

Comment: you can use pure js to create an alert https://stackoverflow.com/a/30498126/4696809

Comment: Disappointing that questions like this wind up attracting a slew of advertisements for mediocre third party packages. I had to sift through half a dozen such "answers" to finally determine that it is in fact not possible.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The alert box is a system object, and not subject to CSS. To do this style of thing you would need to create an HTML element and mimic the `alert()` functionality. The jQuery UI Dialogue does a lot of the work for you, working basically as I have described: [Link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take care 'cause jQueryUI Modal box DOESN'T pause Jquery code execution waiting for user's click (like alert does).

Comment: A good way to handle that is to include event.preventDefault() in your event handler.

Comment: You can use pure js to create an alert https://stackoverflow.com/a/30498126/4696809

Answer (score 82):

I use **[SweetAlert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert),** It's Awesome, You will get lots of customization option as well as all callbacks

[image: Screenshot]

```
swal("Here's a message!", "It's pretty, isn't it?");
```

[image]

Comment: Can we use this in pure javascript and HTML?

Comment: sweetalert is having too many issues + the last publish was 2 years ago, check sweetalert 2 - https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Answer (score 71):

I tried to use script for   **`alert()`** boxes styles using **`java-script`**.Here i used those JS and CSS.

Refer this coding JS functionality.

```
var ALERT_TITLE = "Oops!";
var ALERT_BUTTON_TEXT = "Ok";

if(document.getElementById) {
    window.alert = function(txt) {
        createCustomAlert(txt);
    }
}

function createCustomAlert(txt) {
    d = document;

    if(d.getElementById("modalContainer")) return;

    mObj = d.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
    mObj.id = "modalContainer";
    mObj.style.height = d.documentElement.scrollHeight + "px";

    alertObj = mObj.appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
    alertObj.id = "alertBox";
    if(d.all && !window.opera) alertObj.style.top = document.documentElement.scrollTop + "px";
    alertObj.style.left = (d.documentElement.scrollWidth - alertObj.offsetWidth)/2 + "px";
    alertObj.style.visiblity="visible";

    h1 = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("h1"));
    h1.appendChild(d.createTextNode(ALERT_TITLE));

    msg = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("p"));
    //msg.appendChild(d.createTextNode(txt));
    msg.innerHTML = txt;

    btn = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("a"));
    btn.id = "closeBtn";
    btn.appendChild(d.createTextNode(ALERT_BUTTON_TEXT));
    btn.href = "#";
    btn.focus();
    btn.onclick = function() { removeCustomAlert();return false; }

    alertObj.style.display = "block";

}

function removeCustomAlert() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeChild(document.getElementById("modalContainer"));
}
```

And **CSS** for **`alert()`** Box

```
#modalContainer {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:10000;
    background-image:url(tp.png); /* required by MSIE to prevent actions on lower z-index elements */
}

#alertBox {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    min-height:100px;
    margin-top:50px;
    border:1px solid #666;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:20px 30px;
}

#modalContainer > #alertBox {
    position:fixed;
}

#alertBox h1 {
    margin:0;
    font:bold 0.9em verdana,arial;
    background-color:#3073BB;
    color:#FFF;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    padding:2px 0 2px 5px;
}

#alertBox p {
    font:0.7em verdana,arial;
    height:50px;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-left:55px;
}

#alertBox #closeBtn {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin:5px auto;
    padding:7px;
    border:0 none;
    width:70px;
    font:0.7em verdana,arial;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#357EBD;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* unrelated styles */

#mContainer {
    position:relative;
    width:600px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:5px;
    border-top:2px solid #000;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;
    font:0.7em verdana,arial;
}

h1,h2 {
    margin:0;
    padding:4px;
    font:bold 1.5em verdana;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

code {
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:#069;
}

#credits {
    position:relative;
    margin:25px auto 0px auto;
    width:350px; 
    font:0.7em verdana;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    height:90px;
    padding-top:4px;
}

#credits img {
    float:left;
    margin:5px 10px 5px 0px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    width:80px;
    height:79px;
}

.important {
    background-color:#F5FCC8;
    padding:2px;
}

code span {
    color:green;
}
```

And **HTML file:**

```
<input type="button" value = "Test the alert" onclick="alert('Alert this pages');" />
```

And also View this [DEMO: JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkt91/bds77/) and DEMO RESULT IMAGE

[image]

Comment: But this is custom alert , not styling Original Browser Alert box. Is there any trick, we are still missing ?

Comment: the custom alert in the answer is not compatable to the native alert. The native alert and prompt are block-and-wait.

Comment: How I can make it for the confirmation box ?

Answer (score 11):

Not possible. If you want to customize the dialog's visual appearance, you need to use a JS-based solution like [jQuery.UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 8):

**Option1.** you can use [AlertifyJS](http://alertifyjs.com/) , this is good for alert

[image]

[image]

**Option2.** you start up or just join a project based on webapplications, the design of interface is maybe good. Otherwise this should be changed. In order to Web 2.0 applications you will work with dynamic contents, many effects and other stuff. All these things are fine, but no one thought about to style up the JavaScript alert and confirm boxes.
Here is the they way

create simple js file name jsConfirmStyle.js. Here is simple js code

```
ie5=(document.getElementById&&document.all&&document.styleSheets)?1:0;
nn6=(document.getElementById&&!document.all)?1:0;

xConfirmStart=800;
yConfirmStart=100;

if(ie5||nn6) {
if(ie5) cs=2,th=30;
else cs=0,th=20;
document.write(
    "<div id='jsconfirm'>"+
        "<table>"+
            "<tr><td id='jsconfirmtitle'></td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td id='jsconfirmcontent'></td></tr>"+
            "<tr><td id='jsconfirmbuttons'>"+
                "<input id='jsconfirmleft' type='button' value='' onclick='leftJsConfirm()' onfocus='if(this.blur)this.blur()'>"+
                "&nbsp;&nbsp;"+
                "<input id='jsconfirmright' type='button' value='' onclick='rightJsConfirm()' onfocus='if(this.blur)this.blur()'>"+
            "</td></tr>"+
        "</table>"+
    "</div>"
);
 }

           document.write("<div id='jsconfirmfade'></div>");


function leftJsConfirm() {
document.getElementById('jsconfirm').style.top=-1000;
document.location.href=leftJsConfirmUri;
}
function rightJsConfirm() {
document.getElementById('jsconfirm').style.top=-1000;
document.location.href=rightJsConfirmUri;
}
function confirmAlternative() {
if(confirm("Scipt requieres a better browser!"))       document.location.href="http://www.mozilla.org";
 }

leftJsConfirmUri = '';
rightJsConfirmUri = '';

/**
 * Show the message/confirm box
*/
function showConfirm(confirmtitle,confirmcontent,confirmlefttext,confirmlefturi,confirmrighttext,confirmrighturi)  {
document.getElementById("jsconfirmtitle").innerHTML=confirmtitle;
document.getElementById("jsconfirmcontent").innerHTML=confirmcontent;
document.getElementById("jsconfirmleft").value=confirmlefttext;
document.getElementById("jsconfirmright").value=confirmrighttext;
leftJsConfirmUri=confirmlefturi;
rightJsConfirmUri=confirmrighturi;
xConfirm=xConfirmStart, yConfirm=yConfirmStart;
if(ie5) {
    document.getElementById("jsconfirm").style.left='25%';
    document.getElementById("jsconfirm").style.top='35%';
}
else if(nn6) {
    document.getElementById("jsconfirm").style.top='25%';
    document.getElementById("jsconfirm").style.left='35%';
}
else confirmAlternative();
}
```

Create simple html file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jsConfirmSyle</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsConfirmStyle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function confirmation() {
 var answer = confirm("Wanna visit google?")
 if (answer){
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
}
}
  </script>
   <style type="text/css">
    body {
  background-color: white;
   font-family: sans-serif;
  }
#jsconfirm {
border-color: #c0c0c0;
border-width: 2px 4px 4px 2px;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: -1000px;
z-index: 100;
}

#jsconfirm table {
background-color: #fff;
border: 2px groove #c0c0c0;
height: 150px;
width: 300px;
}

#jsconfirmtitle {
background-color: #B0B0B0;
font-weight: bold;
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

#jsconfirmbuttons {
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
}

#jsconfirmbuttons input {
background-color: #E9E9CF;
color: #000000;
font-weight: bold;
width: 125px;
height: 33px;
padding-left: 20px;
}

#jsconfirmleft{
background-image: url(left.png);
}

#jsconfirmright{
background-image: url(right.png);
}
</style>
```

```
 <p>
<a href="#"  onclick="javascript:showConfirm('Please confirm','Are you really sure to visit google?','Yes','http://www.google.com','No','#')">JsConfirmStyled</a> </p>
<p><a href="#" onclick="confirmation()">standard</a></p>


</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to create your own alert box like this:

```js
function jAlert(text, customokay){
 document.getElementById('jAlert_content').innerHTML = text;
    document.getElementById('jAlert_ok').innerHTML = customokay;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    document.body.style.cursor="wait";
}



jAlert("Stop! Stop!", "<b>Okay!</b>");
```

```css
#jAlert_table, #jAlert_th, #jAlert_td{
    border: 2px solid blue;
    background-color:lightblue;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width=100px;
}

#jAlert_th, #jAlert_td{
    padding:5px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
}

#jAlert{
    /* Position fixed */
    position:fixed;
    /* Center it! */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<p>TEXT</p>
<div id="jAlRem">
    <div id="jAlert">
        <table id="jAlert_table">
            <tr id="jAlert_tr">
                <td id="jAlert_td">  <p id="jAlert_content"></p>  </td>
                <td id="jAlert_td">  <button id='jAlert_ok'  onclick="jAlertagree()"></button>  </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>





<p>TEXT</p>
<p>TEXT</p>
<p>TEXT</p>
<p>TEXT</p>
<p>TEXT</p>
<p>TEXT</p>
<p>TEXT</p>
<p>TEXT</p>
<p>TEXT</p>
<p>TEXT</p>
<p>TEXT</p>
<p>TEXT</p>


<script>
function jAlertagree(){
    var parent = document.getElementById('jAlRem');
    var child = document.getElementById('jAlert');
    parent.removeChild(child);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="white";
    document.body.style.cursor="default";
}
</script>
```

The js portion gets the element in the HTML to create the alert box, then deletes it after the user clicks *ok.*

You can call the alert using `jAlert("Custom Text", "Ok!");`

Comment: +1 Nice sample for start, edit `width=100px;` to `width:100px;` and use classes instead of id, and `#jAlert_th` never used,

Comment: @a55 Yep, all valid points. I must admit that I wrote this almost five years ago when I was still new to web development.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to use [altertify](http://alertifyjs.com/), this gives a nice looking alert box.

Simply include the required libraries from [here](http://alertifyjs.com/guide.html), and use the following piece of code to display the alert box.

```
alertify.confirm("This is a confirm dialog.",
  function(){
    alertify.success('Ok');
  },
  function(){
    alertify.error('Cancel');
  });
```

The output will look like this. To see it in action here is the [demo](http://www.site.uplabs.com/posts/alertifyjs)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an older post but I was looking for something similar this morning.
I feel that my solution was much simpler after looking over some of the other solutions. 
[One thing is that I use font awesome in the anchor tag.](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)

I wanted to display an event on my calendar when the user clicked the event. So I coded a separate `<div>` tag like so:

```
<div id="eventContent" class="eventContent" style="display: none; border: 1px solid #005eb8; position: absolute; background: #fcf8e3; width: 30%; opacity: 1.0; padding: 4px; color: #005eb8; z-index: 2000; line-height: 1.1em;">
        <a style="float: right;"><i class="fa fa-times closeEvent" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><br />
        Event: <span id="eventTitle" class="eventTitle"></span><br />
        Start: <span id="startTime" class="startTime"></span><br />
        End: <span id="endTime" class="endTime"></span><br /><br />
</div>
```

I find it easier to use class names in my jquery since I am using asp.net.

[Below is the jquery for my fullcalendar app.](https://fullcalendar.io/)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            googleCalendarApiKey: 'APIkey',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            events: {
                googleCalendarId: '@group.calendar.google.com'
            },
            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                var stime = calEvent.start.format('MM/DD/YYYY, h:mm a');
                var etime = calEvent.end.format('MM/DD/YYYY, h:mm a');
                var eTitle = calEvent.title;
                var xpos = jsEvent.pageX;
                var ypos = jsEvent.pageY;
                $(".eventTitle").html(eTitle);
                $(".startTime").html(stime);
                $(".endTime").html(etime);
                $(".eventContent").css('display', 'block');
                $(".eventContent").css('left', '25%');
                $(".eventContent").css('top', '30%');
                return false;
            }
        });
        $(".eventContent").click(function() {
            $(".eventContent").css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
</script>
```

You must have your own google calendar id and api keys.

I hope this helps when you need a simple popup display.

Comment: Nothing wrong with answering questions late.  Keeping up-to-date answers is important.

Answer (score 4):

I use `sweetalert2` library. It's really simple, a lot of customization, modern, animated windows, eye-catching, and also nice design.

```
Swal.fire({
  icon: 'error',
  title: 'Oops...',
  text: 'Something went wrong!',
  footer: '<a href>Why do I have this issue?</a>'
})
```

Check this [link](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

Answer (score 3):

```html
<head>
  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
    <script type="text/javascript">
  

$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });
 
    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
   <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
  </div>
 
  <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you could change the style of browsers' default alert boxes.

You need to create your own or use a simple and customizable library like [xdialog](https://github.com/xxjapp/xdialog). Following is a example to customize the alert box. More demos can be found [here](https://xxjapp.github.io/xdialog/).

```js
function show_alert() {
    xdialog.alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/xxjapp/xdialog@3/xdialog.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/xxjapp/xdialog@3/xdialog.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>
        .xd-content .xd-body .xd-body-inner {
            max-height: unset;
        }
        .xd-content .xd-body p {
            color: #f0f;
            text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        }
        .xd-content .xd-button.xd-ok {
            background: #734caf;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Show alert box" />
</body>
```

Comment: one thing is that the alert must be in the middle of the page.

Comment: @MuhammadAliDEV

You can override the default alert effect.

You can open `https://xxjapp.github.io/xdialog/` and try the following line in F12 console yourself.

`xdialog.alert("Hello! I am an alert box!", {effect: 'fade_in_and_scale'});`

Answer (score 1):

Styling alert()-boxes ist not possible. You could use a javascript modal overlay instead.

Answer (score 1):

I use AlertifyJS to style my dialogues.

```js
alertify.alert('Ready!');
alertify.YoutubeDialog || alertify.dialog('YoutubeDialog',function(){
    var iframe;
    return {
        // dialog constructor function, this will be called when the user calls alertify.YoutubeDialog(videoId)
        main:function(videoId){
            //set the videoId setting and return current instance for chaining.
            return this.set({ 
                'videoId': videoId
            });
        },
        // we only want to override two options (padding and overflow).
        setup:function(){
            return {
                options:{
                    //disable both padding and overflow control.
                    padding : !1,
                    overflow: !1,
                }
            };
        },
        // This will be called once the DOM is ready and will never be invoked again.
        // Here we create the iframe to embed the video.
        build:function(){           
            // create the iframe element
            iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.frameBorder = "no";
            iframe.width = "100%";
            iframe.height = "100%";
            // add it to the dialog
            this.elements.content.appendChild(iframe);

            //give the dialog initial height (half the screen height).
            this.elements.body.style.minHeight = screen.height * .5 + 'px';
        },
        // dialog custom settings
        settings:{
            videoId:undefined
        },
        // listen and respond to changes in dialog settings.
        settingUpdated:function(key, oldValue, newValue){
            switch(key){
               case 'videoId':
                    iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + newValue + "?enablejsapi=1";
                break;   
            }
        },
        // listen to internal dialog events.
        hooks:{
            // triggered when the dialog is closed, this is seperate from user defined onclose
            onclose: function(){
                iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}','*');
            },
            // triggered when a dialog option gets update.
            // warning! this will not be triggered for settings updates.
            onupdate: function(option,oldValue, newValue){
                switch(option){
                    case 'resizable':
                        if(newValue){
                            this.elements.content.removeAttribute('style');
                            iframe && iframe.removeAttribute('style');
                        }else{
                            this.elements.content.style.minHeight = 'inherit';
                            iframe && (iframe.style.minHeight = 'inherit');
                        }
                    break;    
                }    
            }
        }
    };
});
//show the dialog
alertify.YoutubeDialog('GODhPuM5cEE').set({frameless:true});
```

```html
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/alertify.min.css"/>
<!-- Default theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/themes/default.min.css"/>
<!-- Default theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/themes/default.rtl.min.css"/>
```