# PHP form pop-up for confirmation request

Tags: php

I would like to implement a pop-up request for the user , e.g. if the user press "yes" for confirm data on MySQL DB are modified otherwise no. This should be done without creating another php confirmation page. I looked through forum discussions , I founded some possible solutions based on Ajax or Javascript but unfortunately I don't know how to programme with these tools.
Can anyone helps?
many thanks

```
//$sql_select= "SELECT .... FROM DB
} 
//------------------Button save data pressed--------------------
if (isset($_POST['bottone_update'])) {
// If te user click confirm button I have to modify the database
    /*$sql_upd = "UPDATE db_sale.prenotazioni_alpha SET VALUES.....*/
    }   
?>

<html>

<head>
</head>

<style type='text/css'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</style>

<body>

<form method="post" action="">
    <!--Table data -->
    <table class='table1' id="pos_table1">
        <tr>
            <td><textarea name="alpha_9_10"></textarea>
                <td>
                    <td><textarea name="meda_9_10"></textarea>
                        <td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><textarea name="alpha_10_11"></textarea>
                <td>
                    <td><textarea name="meda_10_11"></textarea>
                        <td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">look for data</button>
    <button type="submit">Save data</button>
```

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334636/javascript-yes-no-alert/9334685 if you not sure what to do let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add an `onSubmit` attribute to the form, with the JavaScript function `confirm` in it. It will open a pop-up in the browser, asking whatever you define within the first parameter, with two buttons: "OK" and "Cancel". This has the feature of returning true or false (a boolean), when clicking "OK" or "Cancel" respectively.

This means that if you do `onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');"` in the form, you'll be able to send the form *only* if you press "OK" to this check. Then, in PHP, you just check weather or not the form has been submitted; and if it has - you perform your update-query, like you already started doing - no need for additional checks!

```
if (isset($_POST['bottone_update'])) {
    // Perform your query
}
```

Your opening `<form>`-tag should then contain this:

```
<form method="POST" onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
    <!--- Rest of form goes here -->
</form>
```

If you have `action=""`, you can just remove it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    if (confirm('Are You Sure?')) {
        $.post('http://localhost/ajax.php', function () {
            alert('Data Added Successfully!');
        });
    }
});
```