# Invalid if Special Character is entered

Tags: php, jquery, character

I currently have this code below which validates username length only. If none entered it will show error message, if less than 3 characters entered show error message. I want to add an `if/else` statement that if the user enters special characters like `!@#$%^&*()+=/?` etc... the only special character is allowed is underscore (_) and hypen (-)... Help me how.

thanks

here's the code i have:

```
<?php
$serror="";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {              
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $lengt = strlen($username);

    if($lengt == 0){
        $serror=" Please enter account username ";
    }
    else{
        if($lengt < 3 ){            
            $serror=" Please enter valid account username ";
        }
    }
    if($serror==""){
        ob_start();
        echo "Success";
        header("Location:progress.php?username=$username");
        exit;
        ob_end_flush();
    }
    else{}              
}
?>
```

Comment: you can use a regular expression to detect unwanted characters or only allow allowed characters

Answer (score 0):

use `preg_match() function`

```
$yourString = "blahblah";
if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$/', $yourString)) {
    #your string is good
}
```

remeber `preg_match()` returns boolean

Comment: That should work. This pattern should also work: `/^([\w\-]+)$/`

Answer (score 0):

Your php script works after the user submits the form. From your tags in the question I assume you can use javascript. With Javascript you catch these errors before the form is submitted.

So, your html input field would fire a script and you can use the [onkeypress](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp) event to see the value of the keystroke.

The submit button would also have a javascript event to look for min [string length](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp), else give [warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334636/javascript-yes-no-alert) and not submit form.

Comment: This is true, but you should always have validation in the back end as well. People are evil and JS can be manipulated.

Comment: very very true. But since his header is using `GET` method for username, I figured security isn't top priority.

Comment: Oh snap! I missed that one!

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out, you should use regular expressions for this.

Try with the following if-statement (allows a-z, numbers, underscores and hyphens). It also checks that the length is at least 3 characters:

```
if (!preg_match("/^([\w\-]{3,})$/", $username)) {
    $error = "Not enough chars or there are invalid ones".
}
```

Read more about [preg_match() here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: @RachelGallen - Did you notice the exclamation mark `!` in front of `preg_match()`?

Comment: if it doesn't find a match in the first place, well its not gonna make a difference! - it says no match

Comment: It's not suppose to match your string. It contains invalid characters.