# Yes/no alert function with php

Tags: php, alert

I've coded a submit button that deletes the user if the user clicks on it. It sends the data to *delete_data.php* which deletes the data from the SQL db:

[image: Code for the delete button]

I've added an *onclick* attribute the input element, but I want it to display yes/no options and also make sure that if the user clicks "no", it does **not**  send the data to *delete_data.php*

How can I make this happen? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334636/how-to-create-a-dialog-with-yes-and-no-options

Comment: @freddyzcount90 change the order of input elements the element should be `hidden field` first and than `submit button`.

Comment: @mageDev0688 Why?

Comment: @freddyzcount90  because of it's not good practice to handle the data for post on next page. Each form should has all the files which you want to post before the submit button.

Comment: @mageDev0688 i have some pages where my button is on top of all inputs the order does not matter

Answer (score 0):

On your form tag add this instead of your button

```
<form onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete?');">
```

I cannot copy/paste your code as it's image, but i hope you understand.

Comment: I wrote this: onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to delete?'); it worked!

Comment: @freddyzcount90 You should really use `onsubmit` on the form element instead. There are other ways to submit a form than clicking on the submit button, like pressing enter on a form field or button.