# JavaScript confirm on PHP delete button

Tags: javascript, php, html, alert

How can I add a JavaScript alert to confirm (yes or no) when the user clicks the delete button? I tried adding a class to an alert:

```
<?php
//$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "db");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `uploads` where userId = " . $_SESSION['user'];
$qry = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$table_content = "";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $table_content .= "<tr>
                         <td>
                           <a href='listen.php?id=$id' target='_new'>$name </a>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                           <a href='delete.php?id=$id' type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>delete</a>
                         </td>
                       </tr>";
}

echo "<table>".$table_content."</table>";
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: You have to use the `click` event on the button. Use `id` for button and based on that you can show an prompt or `modal` (recommended). And based on that response, use ajax to fire the delete request.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334636/how-to-create-a-dialog-with-yes-and-no-options

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Comment: Tried adding a confirm class to the button and then a Javascript click confirm function (which works on links) but not on the PHP code as shown

Comment: @PhillyHanna Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 6):

For simplicity check this out.

```
<a onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" href='delete.php?id=$id' type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>delete</a>
```

return false is actually doing three very separate things when you call it:

- event.preventDefault();
- event.stopPropagation();
- Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

Since **confirm** method returns true or false, we can simply call it on onclick then the return determines the action.

reference: [kamesh answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25377783/5836034)

```html
 <a onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" href='delete.php?id=$id' type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>delete</a>
```

Comment: Fails to load page :(

Comment: please can you be explicit, make it clearer the explanation

Answer (score 1):

I think thats what you are looking for.

```
<a href='delete.php?id=$id' onclick="return myFunction()" type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>delete</a>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var r = confirm("OK to delete?");
if (r == false) {
   return false;
} 

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, you can give this a whirl!

https://github.com/delboy1978uk/bs-delete-confirm

And if you aren't using bootstrap, give it a shot! Some great functionality ready to rock as soon as you include the css and js! This jQuery delete confirm code uses the Bootstrap modal, see an example here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

```
<a href="http://nasa.gov" class="delete-confirm btn btn-primary">Go!</a>


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.delete-confirm').deleteConfirm();
});
```

See a working Example **HERE** https://jsfiddle.net/myu3kr66/

Answer (score 0):

you can use a modal and on click of delete button, show that modal, 
   in the modal, keep two buttons, yes and no ans assign id to both of       them like, #yes and #no respectively. on click of yes, perform the   delete operation and on click of no, keep the row as it is.

```
<td><a href='listen.php?id=$id' target='_new'>$name </a></td>
<td><a href='delete.php?id=$id' type='button' id="delete"                             

class='btn btn-danger'>delete</a></td>
 </tr>";
}
echo "<table>".$table_content."</table>"

 <script>

$('#delete).on('click',function(){

 $('#modal').show();
 $('#yes').on('click') {
//   perform delete action.
 }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Fails to load page

Comment: this is the basic structure of code, if you show me the issue, I can help you with that

Answer (score 0):

Please follow

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return deleteContent('<?php echo $id; ?>');" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    function deleteContent(id) {
        if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this ?')) {
        window.location='delete.php?id='+id;
        }
    return false;
    }
</script>
```

**Updated**

```
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "db");
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `uploads` where userId = " . $_SESSION['user'];
 $qry = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

 echo "<table>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)){
      $id = $row['id'];
      $name = $row['name'];
?>
<tr>
<td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return deleteContent('<?php echo $id; ?>');" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
<td><a href='listen.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>' target='_new'><?php echo $name; ?> </a></td>
</tr>

<?php } echo "</table>"; ?>
```

Comment: Fails to load page

Comment: I removed the ?> from your code as there is more php after that.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) trying with and without ?>

Comment: Did you see full code that I added to the question at the top?

Comment: yes i have, still is it  not working? what is error?