# If statement based on user input

Tags: javascript

Trying to run a if statement based off a user input, would this be the correct way? So if the user is on a subscription then isSubscription is true.

```
var subscription = window.alert("Is this a subscription? (Y/N)"); 
    if (subscription == "Y") {
        isSubscription = true;
      } else {
        isSubscription = false;
        window.alert("No activation key");
      }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334636/how-to-create-a-dialog-with-yes-and-no-options

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a dialog with “yes” and “no” options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334636/how-to-create-a-dialog-with-yes-and-no-options)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `window.confirm`. It has built in yes/no feature, where value returned are true for yes/ok and false for no/cancel.

So your code would look like

`isSubscription = window.confirm("Is this a subscription?")`

Read more at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Answer (score 1):

Try like this way,

```js
var subscription = window.confirm("Is this a subscription? (Y/N)"); 

    if (subscription == true) {
        window.alert("activation key available");
        isSubscription = true;
      } else {
        isSubscription = false;
        window.alert("No activation key");
      }
```