# Tick checkbox then submit and then pop up window

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, popupwindow

I will appreciate if somebody could help me to find how to solve out one problem, probably I need very simple thing but I don't know how to put it in one, so what I need - Section which include tick box, then button submit, but if you don't tick the check box and push the button appear window which says You must do....,

**I've done it but I need this**

but if you tick and push button should smoothly appear pop up window with just text information! I don't know how to get that,
This is thats section with checkbox and button

```
    <form name="form" method="post" action="#" onSubmit="return checkme();">
    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agree_terms" class="terms">
    &nbsp;I&acute;ve read terms and conditions and I&acute;m ready to shop
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" class="submit">
    </form>
```

and this is javascript

```
    function checkme() {
        missinginfo = "";
        if (!document.form.agree.checked) {
            missinginfo += "You must agree to the Terms and Conditions";
        }
        if (missinginfo != "") {
            missinginfo ="" +
            "\n" +
            missinginfo + "" +
            "\n Please tick the box and try again.";
            alert(missinginfo);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I tried in Different Way

```
    <body>
    <title>LIGHTBOX EXAMPLE</title>
    <style>
    .black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    }
    .white_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 16px solid orange;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <p>This is the main content. To display a lightbox click <a href = "javascript:void(0)"
    onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">here</a></p>

    <div id="light" class="white_content">This is the lightbox content. <a href =                 "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';                document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But when I tick check box on the background appear window with the content but I need pop up window appear only after when I tick the box and push the button

Comment: While I understand what you want. You haven't given us much here. Can you at least show us the HTML code you have now?

Comment: `missinginfo += "You must agree to the Terms and Conditions";` is only used to trigger the send if it exists. Should `missinginfo =""` be `missinginfo +=""`? either way it's redundant. I don't know you have two if statements when one would do. Do you have more code? also `!=` should be `!=='

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"f you tick and push button should smoothly appear pop up window with just text information" - you've almost did it. Just add alert to the second branch. Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <!-- [[[ head -->

  <head>
    <title>element</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkme() {
        if (!document.form.agree.checked) {
            missinginfo = "You must agree to the Terms and Conditions\n Please tick the box and try again.";
            alert(missinginfo);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            alert("Text information");
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
  </head>
  <!-- ]]] -->

  <body>
    <form name="form" method="post" action="#" onSubmit="return checkme();">
      <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree" value="agree_terms" class="terms">
      <label for="agree">&nbsp;I&acute;ve read terms and conditions and I&acute;m ready to shop</label>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me a lot, just I will try to style this windows, or it's not possible?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box

Comment: One questions for just in case, have you got any javascript solution with smooth po up and manual styling?

Comment: No. But try jQuery UI. Look into this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528845/how-do-i-style-the-alert-box-with-css