# How to display font text in red color in alert box?

Tags: javascript, alert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to change the style of alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

I have a requirement in which i need to display font color inside a alert box in red color... Please help....

Comment: nope you can not do that

Comment: http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/02/22/jalert-jquery-alert-box-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do it is to use a jQuery (or other library's) plugin. Or to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A normal alert-box can't be styled. You need an other implementation (like a plugin for jQuery).

You have absolutely no access to the alert-box, the only thing you can modify is the text.