# How to custmize & Design the `alert()` box?

Tags: javascript, alert, right-to-left

Here is script in my [website's](http://latestpknews.tk) footer that will check that specific font installed or not in computer. If installed or not it will prompt alert box. I want to customize:

- Design of that alert box
- Replace the 'OK' button with 'Download' button that also have download link.
- Write some RTL words in new paragraph. For Example Urdu words like `آپ کے کمپیوٹر میں۔۔۔۔`

Comment: You can use lightbox plugins for that

Comment: @XacaXulu You can see code in the footer of website

Comment: Do not replace your existing questions with new ones to circumvent your question ban - that is not allowed. Read the help link that was given to you.

Comment: @BoltClock I am already get ban! But I do not know why.

Comment: Here is the help link again: http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: @BoltClock thanks, next time I will follow rules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change the style of alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just accept that it's not going to be an alert() box, but rather it's just going to be normal HTML+CSS. So you will just position the box wherever you want it with whatever buttons you want and whatever way you want it to look. Or if so you'd whish their are plugins which already do this for you (though they limit your options quite a bit of course). You might want to look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) if you're using jquery for example (specifically the [dialog component](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)).

Comment: It is good idea but how to call the HTML frame? Some guide please.

Comment: Very simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/bEGMD/1/ Though there are lots of other ways to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thank you. That is work fine and exactly that what I want. But I need some more help. Please do not mind. I am new to JS. Now how to put link on "Download" button that will open in same window/tab. Another question is that does JS affect on website's loading speed?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bEGMD/2/ and everything affects website loading speeds, however the effect is so small that that's one thing you won't ever have to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use jquery dialog box for this type of customization. Use [this link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: That is right to use this plugin rather then customize Alert box. It is more flexible to customize. Thanks for nice sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I use Sweetalert for designing the Alert box. its easy, simple and efficient.
here is the link to download [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) and example codes worked out at [Here](http://javainfinite.com/html/custom-designed-alerts/)