# <a href> shows different message in windows and linux server

Tags: php, html, alert

I am using

```
<a href=" <?=base_url(); ?>index.php/admins/candidate/inactive/<?=$list['candidateid']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to inactive this candidate ?');"><img src='/images/inactive.png'> </a>
```

for the delete/inactivate confirmation message in my project.

When I run in my local system I see below message when I click on inactivate link.[image]

and when I deploy the application to linux production server, I get below message. please see below image.[image]

but here in production server, it shows "The page at www.xyz.xom says: ". Why it is that?

Please help, I want to show only message, not the above "The page at..." text.

Comment: thats something which cant be  manipulated... that's a browser issue.. all browsers have their own may of showing alert box.          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box

Answer (score 0):

Its a **security/anti-phishing feature**.

You can try [jquery-alerts](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/)