# How to remove default message from alert box

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, browser, alert

I want to display an alert box which is inside the user control and I bind it through iFrame, but the alert box also contains the default text **"The page  says:"**, however I don't want to display this text.
How to resolve this?
Thanks,

Comment: You can't change that - it's the way the alert() popup box displays and is dependent upon the browser consider jQuery Modal UI elements https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change the style of alert box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

Comment: you can use any other modal popups like bootstrap or jquery modals..etc....

Comment: Is it a javascript alertbox? Try using `alert("<your_text>");`

Comment: Yes! it is javascript alert, and I have tried the same way.