# POP UP window to come from top?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a popup window coming in my web page on click of a button.
I want this popup window to transition from top to the center of the web page on the click of the button
can this be done using CSS?
Thanks.

Comment: Please include code showing what you've tried, an a thorough description of what's going wrong with the code you currently have.

Comment: This is what i have tried , but it didn't work

position: relative;
top: 10px;
width: 500px;
transition-property: top;
transition-delay: 5s;
transition-duration: 5s;

Comment: CSS cannot control window position only element inside the document. Window do have a `moveTo` however. Unless by popup you mean a modal dialog.

Comment: Does this window have to be an alert box? Or can be a customized div?

Comment: yes i mean a modal dialog

Comment: You can use a a third party plugin to do this. http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div id="stage2">
    <div id="box1">#box1</div>
    <div id="box2">#box2</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#stage2 {
   position: relative;
   height: 500px;
   background: #efefef;
   text-align: right;
}
#box1 {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid #666;
   background: red;
   color: #fff;
}
#box2 {
   position: absolute;
   left: 120px;
   top: 0;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid #666;
   background: #00f;
   -webkit-transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
   transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
   color: #fff;
}
#box1:hover + #box2 {
   top: calc(50% - 50px);
   background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: to use this, the two divs should be next to each other.what if they are not next to each other?

Comment: its not a problem. What ever place you gonna put that 2nd div it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit an alert box with just CSS as it is a system object. Try using a [customized div](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/bds77/57/) or [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), or a [plugin](https://www.google.com/search?q=edit+a+alert+box+with+css&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#channel=fflb&q=customizable+alert+box+plugin&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official).
See this SO question about it:
[how to change the style of alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)
Using a customized div is very easy:

```
<div id="cover"><div id="alert"><p>I am a alert!</p><button onclick="hide()">Ok</button></div>
</div>
    <button onclick="show()">Show alert</button>
```

CSS:

```
#cover{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index:999;
    display:none;
}
#alert{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:white;
    margin:200px auto;

}
```

JavaScript:

```
function show(){
     document.getElementById('cover').style.cssText='display:block;';
}
function hide(){
     document.getElementById('cover').style.cssText='display:none;';
}
```