# Change the look of alert box in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, alert

I want to change the look of this alert message:

```
 alert("Hello world");
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please see this -> **http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask** and this -> **http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot, the styling is handled by the browser and is different in every browser. You could use a different solution such as a jQuery UI Dialog https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score -1):

refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7853150/1954925) answer for your alert box styling. It suggests to use jQuery ModelBox instead.