# Tapestry - Alert - Hide Dismiss All

Tags: java, css, alert, tapestry

I have some alerts in my Tapestry web application and it works great but I would like to hide the `Dismiss All` button in my alerts.

I´ve tried it but nothing works. Even css code like this does not work:

```
body DIV.t-dismiss {
    display: none;
}
```

What can I do to remove this button?

Comment: You should probably include the relevant part of DOM here, too. Otherwise one hardly can tell you what CSS to use.

Comment: @YakovL could you help me to do it work?

Comment: Cleared up the text, however I couldnt make the question any better. User input required.

Comment: Like I said, without DOM – nope.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box

Comment: @YakovL what do you want I include here?

Comment: I'm not sure what language is used in your markup -- html, xml or other (is your app a web-server and is viewed in browser, or it is viewed in a standalone app?), but if that's html, show html, if xml, show xml, although if it is manipulated dynamicly, the static markup may be not enough. But let's start from that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it and it was easy...

```
<t:alerts showDismissAll="false"/>
```

instead

```
<t:alerts/>
```

on my tml file.