# returning a custom dialog box from a conditional javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, dialog, conditional-statements, customization

This is my javascript function to check whether a file uploaded is an image format type one! currently i have used the default alert box to return the error message!

```
 var _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png"];    
function Validate(oForm) {
    var arrInputs = oForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
        var oInput = arrInputs[i];
        if (oInput.type == "file") {
            var sFileName = oInput.value;
            if (sFileName.length > 0) {
                var blnValid = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                    var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                    if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                        blnValid = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!blnValid) {

                    alert("Sorry a dig copy may be in a different file format! Formats allowed are " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The following code gives a customised dialog box which i want to call instead of the default box

```
<style>
            #white-background{
                display: none;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                background-color: #fefefe;
                opacity: 0.7;
                z-index: 9999;
            }

            #dlgbox{
                /*initially dialog box is hidden*/
                display: none;
                position: fixed;
                width: 480px;
                z-index: 9999;
                border-radius: 10px;
                background-color: #7c7d7e;

            }

            #dlg-header{
                background-color:aliceblue;
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
            }

            #dlg-body{
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
                font-size: 14px;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
            }

            #dlg-footer{
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
                text-align: right;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
            }

            #dlg-footer button{
                background-color: grey;
                color: white;
                padding: 5px;
                border: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- dialog box -->
        <div id="white-background">
        </div>
        <div id="dlgbox">
            <div id="dlg-header"></div>
            <div id="dlg-body">Sorry a dig copy may be in a different file format! Formats allowed are ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png"</div>
            <div id="dlg-footer">
                <button onclick="dlgLogin()">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- rest of the page -->
        <h1>Dialog Box Demo</h1>
        <p>This is a dialog box example.</p>
        <p>Feel free to experiment with the code.</p>
        <p>Click the button below to see the dialog box.</p>
        <button onclick="showDialog()">Click Me!</button>

        <!-- script of dialog -->
        <script>
            function dlgLogin(){
                var whitebg = document.getElementById("white-background");
                var dlg = document.getElementById("dlgbox");
                whitebg.style.display = "none";
                dlg.style.display = "none";
            }

            function showDialog(){
                var whitebg = document.getElementById("white-background");
                var dlg = document.getElementById("dlgbox");
                whitebg.style.display = "block";
                dlg.style.display = "block";

                var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
                var winHeight = window.innerHeight;

                dlg.style.left = (winWidth/2) - 480/2 + "px";
                dlg.style.top = "150px";
            }
        </script>
```

Please help me to integrate the 2nd code into the 1st code so that i can return the customised dialog box instead of the default alert box

Comment: Just call `showDialog()` instead of `alert()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answere here [how to change the style of alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

```
The alert box is a system object, and not subject to CSS. To do this style of thing you would need to create an HTML element and mimic the alert() functionality. The jQuery UI Modal box does a lot of the work for you, working basically as I have described: Link.
```