# Why does alert return this way in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Folks! I'm wondering where to start to understand why JavaScript alert returns in Chrome in this way. Can it be lacking JavaScript in PHP source code? .Where should I start to understand and diagnose the problem?

My Script

```html
 "<script type='text/javascript'>
           $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#menu2').click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
   
          alert('Text');
            })
            });
            </script>";
```

Result Chrome:

[image]

Result Mozilla

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What is the problem?

Comment: @Renato the 2nd screenshot is modal feature in bootstrap.

Comment: please add your code so we can help you

Comment: The first screenshot is what the native alert dialog looks like. You'll have to explain why you expect it to look like the second screenshot instead.

Comment: Yes. I got this bootbox sample screen but I can change it if I have to. I want to understand why this happens to my <script> </ script>. And show in the second image how I wish it was the return.

Comment: I want to understand why the alternative is returning.

Comment: So the alert will run natively by Chrome with no other solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change the style of alert box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the default pop ups in chrome don't look good is because they aren't really important, so there's no reason for the developers at Google to spend a bunch of time designing and building beautiful ones. If you look at the pop ups in most other browsers (to the best of my knowledge), they will look similar.

Your second screenshot looks like some sort of modified version (possibly bootstrap?) and has absolutely nothing to do with the default pop up.

So to answer your question, no, there is no missing javascript or PHP source code. It's just a design choice on the part of Google to focus resources into more important areas.

If you want to change the look, you can't. It's part of the browser, not part of the website. But, if you really need to have a better looking one (and I would strongly recommend you look into different options as pop ups are bad UX), http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ will be able to help.

Comment: What can I do to improve the look of the alert?

Comment: See new edit for more details

Comment: I tried using http://bootboxjs.com/ to get a better visual result, however I could not implement it to my JavaScript code above. I think it would be ideal. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Start a new question, mention that you have tried using bootbox to get a better look, post the code that you've tried and it will be a lot easier to help you

Comment: I post a new question about:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819330/how-to-leave-my-alert-with-better-looking-using-modal