# Accepting alerts triggered by JavaScript

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

Why isn't it possible (using the `InternetExplorerDriver`) to accept alerts which have been triggered by explicitly executing JavaScript?

```
driver.ExecuteJavaScript("myfuncTriggeringAnAlert()");

var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var alert = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
alert.Accept();
```

The code works great using `ChromeDriver`, unfortunately however, the `InternetExplorerDriver` does not even return from the `ExecuteJavaScript()` call. It simply times out after 60 seconds.

Any ideas? Is this well-known behavior?

IE11 + IE Driver 2.48.0

Comment: (same behavior with IE Driver 3.0)

Comment: Yes, there are few bugs in handling alerts/prompts/confirms with `IE Driver`...actually with `chromedriver` also :)

Comment: Oh... I missed one detail :) You skipped switching to alert! `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());` doesn't allow you to to accept alert: you need something like `alert.switch_to_alert()` (`Python` syntax) or `alert.switchTo().alert();` (`Java` syntax)... sorry, I can't recognize your programming language, also you didn't add appropriate tag

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `window.alert` function of JavaScript. It does not behave the same way in Internet Explorer than in other browsers. Selenium WebDriver is not able to handle it properly, for the best of my knowledge the only thing you can do is closing it manually in IE.

So, I would change your function `myfuncTriggeringAnAlert` to avoid to use native alerts. Maybe you can use a custom alert dialog, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box).

Comment: Actually, in general one can accept alert triggered by `window.alert()` with `IE Driver`, but in some cases issues could occur

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot change to another alert library and have to stick to native alerts. We are now manually testing the alert behavior in IE instead of using Selenium :-(