# How to give customize alert oe strip in html with button

Tags: javascript, html

I need to show some message before loading the page so I am giving an alert message, but I can not customise my alert window. Therefor I am trying to achive this in html. BUt Not getting success.

I want an alert window like this.

Image.

Here is my code with alert.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert("Hello");
</script>
```

Here is the code what I am trying to get the window.

```
<frameset rows="20%">
  <frame text="Hello">
</frameset>
```

In my frame set I am getting nothing. DO I need to use any other tag or something to achive this. I need button with handler too like alert.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box

Comment: use `confirm('Your string');`

Comment: You need to create your own alert window: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: here is a working version http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: checking the same

Comment: @marmeladze Instead of close I want "OK" Button. IS it possible to place button on modelbox.

Comment: of course it is possible. i've posted as an answer. look if it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below snippet.
Forked from - http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var okbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
okbtn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="close">OK</button> 
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works like charm. One quick question any way I can place "OK" text in right side :) Thanks again for help

Comment: ofcourse, just give style to `close` class. let me update the answer. i've pulled it right, you should give a bit margin.

Comment: thanjs a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify look & feel of standard alert popup. For custom alert consider using jQuery (https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or bootstrap (https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/).

Comment: IS it possible to work around javascript. Not sure how to implement jquery in html page

Comment: check link provided by @marmeladze

Comment: Thanks this is working. But page is also loading in background.

Comment: Which solution did  you try?

Comment: what @marmeladze gave, by using model.