# How can i customized alert box in my code

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In [php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODaiu.png), I am including the alert box to show the errors and this is working. Now I want to make stylish my alert box E.g: colors, font style, bgcolor etc.

Comment: 1- http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

2- http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: 3. [sweet alert.](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

Comment: 0. Go read [ask], please.

Answer (score 0):

`window.alert()` is not customizable. You will have to use an overlay or a pop up. Don't use a pop up, though.

Answer (score 0):

The alert box is a system object, and not subject to CSS. To do this style of thing you would need to create an HTML element and mimic the `alert()` functionality. The jQuery UI Modal box does a lot of the work for you, working basically as I have described: [Link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Reference by [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box/7853150#7853150)

**Try this**

```
<?php
     $my = "hello";

     echo "<script>alert('".$my."'); window.location.href='index.php';</script>";

 ?>
```

Comment: and how can i customized this alert box...?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box/7853150#7853150