# Ignore the alert message localhost in popup

Tags: jsp

While raising the alert message in jsp and it showing extra mssage in alert box.
Could you please let me know how to ignore this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("password invalid")  
</script>
```

[[image]]

Thanks,
Murali

Comment: what you mean extra message ? `localhost:7070 says`?

Comment: yes,how to ignore the message.Could you please help on this one

Comment: You need to customise this .Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box