# How to change the size of the input area on a prompt box?

Tags: javascript

I am using a simple JS here:

```
var person = prompt("how are you feeling today?", "");
```

And I would like the text input area (NOT the whole box, ONLY the area where you type in the text) to be bigger... like a comment section.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change the style of alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

Comment: You don't. `prompt()` and `alert()` are not supposed to be for Real World Use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text input box here is supplied by the browser of the client and therefore cannot be changed in any way with CSS styling. You could instead create a custom popup which is part of your website, allowing you to style it however you would like.

Comment: I was afraid of that ;/ Thanks Matthew