# Modified style of alert box (JavaScript on browser)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How to change the default JavaScript alerts from the browser to make it better?
I've read [how to change the style of alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box) , but it's based on the click of a button .. I mean the alert which is the default browser without having to click the button. 
here's an example:

```
<?php
    include 'libraries/config.php';     

$id      = $_GET['id'];
$cart_id = $_GET['cart_id'];

    $myqry=mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM cart_order_detail WHERE id='$id'");

    if ($myqry)
    {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Are you sure want delete this item ?');document.location='order.php';</script>";
    }
?>
```

[image]

can possible ?

Comment: You can not modify its style .. you have to generate your own model to do that .... :(

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @PranavDeshpande do you use jquery?

Comment: Yes ... you can use model and style that accordingly

Comment: The linked question also applies to your question..

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to style alert box modal. Because it is operating system native element and does not appear to be a part of DOM in any way.

You will need to create your own modal to be able to style it.

**Please note**: alert() stops execution of js on your page, and usually this is not desirable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Web browsers do not provide a way for a website to override the look and feel of their native dialog boxes.

The only way to do it is to fake it by creating elements in the DOM which look like dialogs (the approach you dismissed in the question).

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. `alert` cannot be styled by CSS or configured. If you want to display something custom you should create your own or use a third party library like [sweet alert](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) or jQuery UI or anything.

Take care that these tools doesn't block the execution of the rest of the JavaScript code like `alert`