# alert() in mac OS design in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, alert

I am inspired by this thread [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkt91/bds77) to create javascript `alert()` with css design but I am trying to do this alert in Mac OS design, but I couldn't achieve this.

It will your kind help help , How I convert my code in alert so that when I run `alert('{MY_Content}')` in Javascript or jQuery it will show in my design as like this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkt91/bds77):

My Code is below which show in Mac Design and here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/techWorld/f0qLzjsn/) :

It will your so kind to help me, Please help.. :(

```css
.window.warning {
  width: 400px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 15%;
  margin: 0px 0 0 -200px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
}

.window.windows-vis {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.window {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(233, 233, 233, 1.0), rgba(178, 178, 178, 1.0) 21px, #EDEDED, #EDEDED 23px);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(233, 233, 233, 1.0), rgba(178, 178, 178, 1.0) 21px, #EDEDED, #EDEDED 23px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .6), 0 22px 70px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.tab {
  height: 21px;
}

nav.control-window {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 19px;
}

nav.control-window a.close {
  background: #FD4E4E;
}

nav.control-window a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0px 3px 1px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  text-indent: -9999px;
  position: relative;
}

nav.control-window a:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

nav.control-window a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 2%, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, .4) 16%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 43%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .74), rgba(255, 255, 255, .7) 122%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .7));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 2%, white, rgba(255, 255, 255, .4) 16%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 43%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .74), rgba(255, 255, 255, .7) 122%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .7));
  box-shadow: inset 0px -3px -5px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0px 2px -5px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

nav.control-window a.minimize {
  background: #F3BB55;
}

nav.control-window a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0px 3px 1px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  text-indent: -9999px;
  position: relative;
}

nav.control-window a.maximize {
  background: #96D16F;
}

nav.control-window a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0px 3px 1px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  text-indent: -9999px;
  position: relative;
}

h1.titleInside {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #3c3c3c;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #e7e7e7;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid #656565;
}

.container-alert img {
  float: left;
}

.container-alert {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.about-alert {
  width: 295px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.about-alert p {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

a.button.blink {
  height: 19px;
  line-height: 19px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 15px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 19px 0 rgba(0, 115, 215, 0.3), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #D3F7FD), color-stop(0.5, #87C5FB), color-stop(0.5, #A1D1F9), color-stop(1, #D4E9FC));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, #D3F7FD 0%, #87C5FB 50%, #A1D1F9 50%, #D4E9FC 100%);
  border-top-color: #5a5caf;
  border-bottom-color: #52536f;
  border-left-color: #56578f;
  border-right-color: #56578f;
  -webkit-animation: blinking 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: blinking 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}

a.button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-size: 11px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #9a9a9a;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #EBEBEB), color-stop(0.5, #ECECEC), color-stop(0.5, #F3F3F3), color-stop(1, #FFFFFF));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, #EBEBEB 0%, #ECECEC 50%, #F3F3F3 50%, #FFFFFF 100%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
}

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
font,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="warning" class="window warning ui-draggable windows-vis" style="display: block;">
  <div class="tab"></div>
  <nav class="control-window">
    <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
    <a href="#" class="minimize">minimize</a>
    <a href="#" class="maximize">maximize</a>
  </nav>
  <h1 class="titleInside">Share This</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-alert">
      <img src="http://www.alessioatzeni.com/mac-osx-lion-css3/res/img/Alert.png" alt="alert">
      <div class="about-alert">
        <h2>Alert</h2>
        <p>This application cannot be used in this version</p>
        <a href="#warning" class="button blink" data-rel="close">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do what they did. Set `window.alert` to a custom function. Should look like `window.alert = function(){}`. This overrides the default alert and replaces it

Comment: You can follow this example of custom popup : [w3schools - howto js popup](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp)

Comment: @Shim-Sao This is normal popup or tooltip and I would to do this in JS when I user `alert()` this will show my code instead default alert looks

Comment: Styling default alert is not possible, all you can do is to override the `window.alert`. If you search a little, it's a duplicated question with all JSFiddle you want: [how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the first link posted, it shows how. Here’s the line that makes it happen

```
window.alert = function(txt) {
        createCustomAlert(txt);
    }
```

What this does is make the `alert()` function into your own custom function instead of the default. They used a separate function, `createCustomAlert`. You’ll want to create your own function.

I would just set the container of the alert’s `style` property through JS. Instead of `display:block;`, use `display:none;`. There are other ways to accomplish this, of course. Here’s an example:

```
document.getElementById(‘container-id’).style = ‘display:none;’;
```

Another way is to create a class that is always hidden. You would then add or remove this class when you would like to toggle hiding the alert.
This requires JavaScript, which I see you’re not yet using.

Comment: Could you sir please provide me the JSFiddle pLs

Comment: Which one? What do you mean? I didn’t make a JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a JS file as well. Your JS file will contain your custom alert function. And you will override the default alert function by the line

```
window.alert = myAlertFunction
```

And you would create a function 'myAlertFunction' which would have one parameter, which would be the text to be displayed in the alert.

You can just use the one in the first JSFiddle if you want.

```
function myAlertFunction(txt) {
    d = document;

    if(d.getElementById("modalContainer")) return;

    mObj = d.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
    mObj.id = "modalContainer";
    mObj.style.height = d.documentElement.scrollHeight + "px";

    alertObj = mObj.appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
    alertObj.id = "alertBox";
    if(d.all && !window.opera) alertObj.style.top = document.documentElement.scrollTop + "px";
    alertObj.style.left = (d.documentElement.scrollWidth - alertObj.offsetWidth)/2 + "px";
    alertObj.style.visiblity="visible";

    h1 = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("h1"));
    h1.appendChild(d.createTextNode(ALERT_TITLE));

    msg = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("p"));
    //msg.appendChild(d.createTextNode(txt));
    msg.innerHTML = txt;

    btn = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("a"));
    btn.id = "closeBtn";
    btn.appendChild(d.createTextNode(ALERT_BUTTON_TEXT));
    btn.href = "#";
    btn.focus();
    btn.onclick = function() { removeCustomAlert();return false; }

    alertObj.style.display = "block";

}
```

Finally, a small function to remove the alert

```
function removeCustomAlert() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeChild(document.getElementById("modalContainer"));
}
```

[This](https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Custom-Alert-Box-Programming-Tutorial) is a good video which explains how to do everything step by step if you are feeling lost.

Comment: thanks you sir, but this is not working when I run this in JsFiiddle please have a look here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/techWorld/0ex8ym5j/1/)