# Iphone X viewport switching from portrait to landscape causes top of page to be unclickable

Tags: css, ios, iphone, viewport

Issue with link at top of the page on iPhone X becomming unclickable after rotating from portrait to landscape. While in portrait mode click 'Hide Toolbar' then rotate to landscape. Using the following code I can't seem to be able to click the 'Close' button. Is the top of the screen an unclickable area reserved for the address bar?

JSFiddle with code: https://jsfiddle.net/k673b48n/1/

Am I missing something in my code? Is this a bug of some kind?

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
```

```
<style>
  .header { position: absolute; right: 5px; }
  .alert-me:before { content: "Close"; position: absolute; top: 2px; left: -47px; }
  .container{ position: absolute; top: 50px; }
</style>
```

```
<div class="header">
  <a href="#" onclick="alert('Ahhh General Kenobi')">
    <div class="alert-me">X</div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="container">
Some lorem ipsum to make the page longer..
</div>
```

This seems to work fine:

[image: portrait - works]

Close at the top of the page is now non responsive:

[image: landscape - not working]

Comment: I tested it and it works fine. There might be problems but I don't get any.

Answer (score 1):

`position:absolute` removes element from the normal document flow. And the element is positioned relative to its nearest positioned element, if any; else, it is positioned relative to its initial container. **MAYBE** on Safari, it does not do. So you may use `position:relative` on `<body>` to make sure that it is inside the `<body>`. And you may also use a large number `z-index` to arrange the header at the top of the stacking context.

More info:

[position-absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

[z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index)

[stacking-context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

---

If you do not need to change the normal flow of the document, you may use `display:flex; justify-content: flex-end;` instead of `absolute` positioning to place the X element at the right most.

```css
.d-flex {
  display:flex;
}
.justify-content-end {
 justify-content: flex-end;
}

.align-items-center {
   align-items: center;
}


.pr-5px {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center pr-5px">
  <a href="#" onclick="alert('Ahhh General Kenobi')">
    <div class="alert-me">X</div>
  </a>
</header>


<div class="container">
Some lorem ipsum to make the page longer..
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this issue on **iPhone 8** and **Xs**, Safari browser. Did exactly what you described. While in portrait mode I clicked on 'Hide Toolbar' then rotate to landscape.

**iPhone 8:**
First time was exactly like you described, although when I get back to the portrait mode - alert didn't work either. But! After reloading the page - i couldn't repeat the issue. Everything began to work just fine. After hiding toolbar and changing orientation - i'm clicking on *Close*, full toolbar appears and the alert works fine. I'have tried different combination, reloaded the page, app, reopened tab - works fine.

**iPhone Xs:** Exactly like you described. The issue can be repeated every time i reloaded page. Sometimes *Close* button not responding even after I rotate phone back to portrait mode. Sometimes on the 3-4 time of clicking the alert appears like it should be.

**Summary**

1. This is definitely a Safari + iPhone X(s) bug, although can be detected on other models of iPhone.
2. This problem isn't associated with *Close* button on the top edge of the screen, it is definitely an **Alert window** problem. You can use some tips howto [replace standard alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box).