# How can I set a "You've subscribed" notification in html when someone enters their email and subscribes?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS and I created a subscription box where people can enter their emails. I used ruby and SendGrid. I would like to notify people that they have subscribed once they click the subscribe button. Either a pop-up or just text would be great. How can I accomplish this? Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use javascript alert like below.

```js
var myFunction = function() {
alert('you did it!')
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">click me!</a>
```

this is obviously the easier solution. But you can also create an html div toggling display none css class.

Comment: Thanks so much, that was a huge help. Do you know if there is a way to edit the alert, e.g. font, size, color, etc. ?

Comment: i think this should be what you want to know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box

Comment: Thank you so much.