# How can I customize an alert in JavaScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, alerts

I am using TypeScript in React. I would like to create custom alerts and add to them images. I used
this method:

```
private alert() {
    alert("This is an Alert Dialog");
  }
```

Do you have any idea how to customize it?

Thans in advance for tips.

Comment: The alert box can't be customized

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the style of alert box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may want to look for is a modal box,
as you could style that so display alerts.

This page can help you get started:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Or look into bootstrap which simplifies modals a lot: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Answer (score 1):

The alert box is a system object, and not subject to CSS. You might want to use a third party library for that or add your own alert popup. Either way you can't style the default alert box.

Comment: You can find more information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box

Answer (score 0):

You need to use modals. Here it is a sample:

```
import React from "react";

export const Modal = ({modalContent, style}) => {

    return (
        <div className="modal" style={style}>
            {modalContent}
        </div>
    );
};
```

And usage is like this:

```
import { Modal } from '../Shared/Modal';

....

                {this.state.Modal && <Modal style={{ animation: "fadeIn 1s, scaleUp 1s" }}
                    modalContent={
                        <div className="Add-BillRange">
                           <h1> MODAL </h1>
                        </div>
                    }
                />}
```

`this.state.Modal` controls if the modal should be showed or not.