# Style text in popup

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to style the text in the below popup. I would like to have the text show on 2 lines i.e. `Message sent successfully.` should be on one line and `One of our consultants will contact you within the next 2 business days.` should be on another line. Is there anyway I can possibly append HTML to it?

```
  onGetAdvice() {
    this.loader.start();
    this.getAdvice().subscribe((resp) => {
      this.loader.stop();
      this.infoPopupService.openInfoPopup('Message sent successfully. One of our consultants will contact you within the next 2 business days.');
      this.showConnectWindow = false;
    }, error => {
      this.loader.stop();
      console.log(error.statusText);
    });
  }
```

Comment: New-line (`\n`) for text (`pre` if HTML text) or in the console. Use `<br>` inside HTML text.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to use a HTML popup with something like this I've found on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```