# Can you customize the alert box in userChrome.css?

Tags: css, firefox, customization, userchrome.css

I recently discovered FireFox's `userChrome.css` where you can cutsomize about everything with CSS. I tried googling how I can customize the alert box (when I use '`alert()`') but I can't find anything. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the style of alert box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Normal! According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box), Javascript alert boxes are system objects and not modifiable by CSS. However, you should rarely encounter one while using Firefox, and if you're in the process of writing a webextension, it's much better to write your own [notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Notifications) or [popup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Popups).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you could make your own.

Comment: Yep. It's actually better for a multitude of reasons, least of which is that the JS alert box halts all other JS processes until it's dismissed. We're all here to learn new things :) Goodness knows I've asked my fair share of silly or duplicate questions on this site.