# hello, can I ask what is better alternative for the alert in javascript? Like, i want something more creative, where I can customize the pop up box

Tags: javascript, alert, customization

Also i tried creating customize alert box using html,css and javascript, but my problem is how can I call it in the echo function of PHP?

```
if (($con -> query($query) === TRUE) &&
($con -> query($query1) === TRUE) &&
($con -> query($query2) === TRUE) &&
($con -> query($query3) === TRUE))
{
   echo "<script>alert('Employee Successfully Added')</script>";
}
```

like if the queries are correct, the customized alert box will pop up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the style of alert box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

Answer (score -1):

use sweetalert

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

```
Swal.fire({
  position: 'top-end',
  icon: 'success',
  title: 'Your work has been saved',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 1500
})
```

Comment: is there anyway I can call this in the echo part? like in here echo "<script>alert('Employee Successfully Added')</script>";

Comment: how do I call this alert?