# How to make this line bold?

Tags: jquery, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing the way a JavaScript Alert() or Prompt() looks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056770/changing-the-way-a-javascript-alert-or-prompt-looks)

I have a string in my JavaScript code here:

```
_msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";
```

I am displaying `_msg` using `alert`.

How can I make it bold?

Comment: Based on you question: **You want to make a string variable bold**... You can't. you can do zoom in, but that's the best you can! **lol**

Comment: This is your guide:  https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: No not the variable, What I mean is that when I display this string on screen, I want it to display the string in bold font, so is there a way to do this?

Comment: _msg is displayed in an alert, I want the _msg in the alert to be bold

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is way too vague to know what you're actually doing with that string, but in the off chance you're just sticking it in the DOM somewhere:

```
_msg = "<b>You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "</b>\n";
```

**Edit:** You're displaying it in an alert, sorry there isn't any control over the formatting in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't style HTML content in alert pop-ups.

Your best bet is looking into a custom pop-up, which you can style with CSS and toggle with Jquery.

This tutorial is fairly simple as it only requires the Jquery library:

http://webdesignersdesk.com/2010/05/create-custom-popup-model-window-with-jquery/

There are also several plugins available for custom pop-ups too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bold text in an `alert`. Sorry.

However, you can add something in the DOM that looks like an alert.