# Java Script var answer size

Tags: javascript, size

Any way to change the size of the JavaScript popup text?

The following does not work:

```
var answer = confirm("Have you checked your basket?\n\n You really really sure that you checked your basket?")
var answer= str.fontsize(7);
```

Comment: Nope. You will have to use custom dialogs. You can use jquery for this purpose.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056770/changing-the-way-a-javascript-alert-or-prompt-looks