# Customize javascript prompt and confirmation box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am very new in HTML design. My front end is in **Angular.js**. In my application, some method is executed and prompts for user input. After the user input it proceeds with rest of the logic.

Currently, I am using simple `confirm()` or `prompt()`. But I need to have html template instead of typical message. I tried something like below.

```
var htmlStr = "<div> This is nice html with <h1>header</h1> and body content </div>";
var action = prompt(htmlStr);
```

It shows up as a string and not as html.

Any idea how shall convert into  html? Any help/suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7056787/4759033

Comment: Thanks for the link - very useful to me

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The extent of modifying text in a `prompt`, `alert`, or `confirm` popup is limited to adding a `\n` character to the string to add a break line. (Might be a few other escaped characters, but no html allowed.) The style of these popups is completely up to the browser.

[window.prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)

What you can do is create a custom modal using a `position:absolute` or `relative` div styled to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sweetalert to show customize javascript prompt or confirmation box.

```
swal({
    title: "An input!",
    text: "Write something interesting:",
    type: "input",   showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    animation: "slide-from-top",
    inputPlaceholder: "Write something" },
    function (inputValue) {
        if(inputValue === false) {
            return false;
        }

        if(inputValue === "") {
            swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");

            return false;
        }

        swal("Nice!", "You wrote: " + inputValue, "success");
    }
);
```

demo https://jsfiddle.net/szf1jgog/

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  swal({
      title: "An input!",
      text: 'Write something interesting:',
      type: 'input',
      showCancelButton: true,
      closeOnConfirm: false,
      animation: "slide-from-top",
      inputPlaceholder: "Write something",
    },
    function(inputValue) {
      if (inputValue === false) return false;

      if (inputValue === "") {
        swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
        return false;
      }

      swal("Nice!", 'You wrote: ' + inputValue, "success");

    });
};
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<button>Alert me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks like it has angular wrapper as well. Will check it out. Btw instead of text can I use html template?

Answer (score 0):

Prompt method takes in only string as its parameter so, any `html` code you pass in will also be taken as string only. If your project is in angularjs, then I would suggest you to have a look at [angular-ui Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

This has native angular directives for all the common use-cases. You can use `modal` to get the user input and style it as you want.